# Как организовать передачу ошибки между классами?

Tags: c++, исключения, перегрузка-операторов, try-catch

К примеру у меня есть MyClass с последующим кодом(реализация остальных перегрузок есть в .cpp файле, но они не имеют дела к моему вопросу, ибо он касается перегрузки выделения памяти):

```
#include "Stdafx.h"
#include "ExceptionOutputInput.h"
#ifndef _MY_CLASS_H_
#define _MY_CLASS_H_

class MyClass {

private:

    int* ptr;
    int size;
    int* forbiddenArray;
    int counter;


public:

    MyClass();
    MyClass(int sizeOfArray);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const MyClass& object);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, MyClass& object);
    MyClass& operator=(const MyClass& object);
    void* operator new(size_t size) {

        void* ptr_;
        cout << "memory extracting" << endl;
        ptr_ = malloc(size);
        if (!ptr_) {

            cout << "error" << endl;
            throw "division by zero!";

        }else{

            cout << "memory allocated" << endl;
            return ptr_;
        }

    }
    friend class ExceptionOutputInput;
};

#endif //MYCLASS
```

а так же есть класс что должен обрабатывать ошибку выделения динамической памяти, он в данный момент пуст, но думаю что стоит показать его(он является наследником класса Exception, который в свою очередь аналогично пуст):

```
#ifndef _EXCEPTION_OUTPUT_INPUT_H_
#define _EXCEPTION_OUTPUT_INPUT_H_
#include "Stdafx.h"
#include "Exception.h"

class ExceptionOutputInput : public Exception {

private:


public:

    friend class MyClass;

};
#endif //EXCEPTIONOUTPUTINPUT
```

Вопрос в том, каким образом мне организовать передачу ошибки из первого класса(MainClass) в ExceptionOutputInput? Пытался через дружественные классы(прописано friend class "class_name") но не выходит. Т.е перегрузка выделения памяти, должна передавать в последний класс ошибку, в котором она же должна обрабатываться. Лучше конечно чтобы ошибка передавалась в exception класс(родитель ExceptionOutputInput) а уже родительский класс сам бы распределял куда нужно передать ошибку для обработки. Или эта схема очень мудреная и может не работать?

Comment: Путь обработки исключений идет по стеку, вызываются все деструкторы объектов в данной нити. Словить исключение вы можете в любом месте, где надо. Может быть вы хотели так: `try{...}catch(ExceptionOutputInput){...}`? И вызывать так : `throw ExceptionOutputInput;`

Comment: если хотите передовать ошибку посредствам `throw`, то ваш класс `ExceptionOutputInput` должен иметь метод (или статическую функцию) в котором вызывается ваша функция, бросающая исключения. Чтобы не делать это хардкодом можно использовать вариативный шаблон. Но я бы подумал над другим способом обработки ошибкок - исключения удобно обрабатывать в блоках, а если вы проверяете каждую функцию, то разумнее использовать другие способы, например по возвращаемому значению

Answer (score 0):

Путь обработки исключений идет по стеку, вызываются все деструкторы объектов в данной нити. Словить исключение вы можете в любом месте, где надо. Может быть вы хотели так: `try{...}catch(ExceptionOutputInput){...}`? И вызывать так : `throw ExceptionOutputInput;`

если хотите передовать ошибку посредствам `throw`, то ваш класс `ExceptionOutputInput` должен иметь метод (или статическую функцию) в котором вызывается ваша функция, бросающая исключения. Чтобы не делать это хардкодом можно использовать вариативный шаблон. Но я бы подумал над другим способом обработки ошибкок - исключения удобно обрабатывать в блоках, а если вы проверяете каждую функцию, то разумнее использовать другие способы, например по возвращаемому значению